# How to add an activity to a widget

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

i created a small widget app. Yesterday i decided add more functionality to the program, so i need an activity, because the widget looks good but i want to serve more information in my app for the users (listview, buttons that's what i need).
So in the /layout folder i created a "config.xml" for the graphical design of the activity. This has only a textview, no need for coding.

Then i created the MainActivity.java, which looks easy as hell:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.config);
     TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);  
     txt.setText("Something");
 }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bfarago.hellowidget"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">


    <receiver android:name=".HelloWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".UpdateService" />


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                      android:label="@string/hello">
            <intent_filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent_filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Problem is, when i launch the app I cannot see it's icon among the other application.
What do i miss?

Answer (score 0):

The AndroidManifest.xml specifies that the default "Droid" icon should appear in the apps grid - the default name (from **res/values/strings.xml**) is "**User Application**".  Is it there?

By "launch the app" do you mean the widget or the activity?  An activity, of course, normally takes the display and hides any other icons or apps.